# How to bind a JComboBox selectedItem to a Jtable by code using binding classes?

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable, jcombobox

I m successfully binding a JTextField to a selected row from a JTable using this code :

```
public static final void BindTableToFields(JTable Table, Object[] Fields) {

    for (Object Field : Fields) {

        BeanProperty<JTable, Object> tableBeanProperty;

        String DesignCallID;
        String PropertyName;

        if (Field instanceof JTextField) {
            BeanProperty<JTextField, String> BindingFieldProperty;
            Binding<JTable, Object, JTextField, String> binding;
            JTextField jTextField = (JTextField) Field;
            DesignCallID = jTextField.getText();
            PropertyName = "selectedElement." + GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID);
            jTextField.setText("");
            System.out.println("property name =" + PropertyName.trim());

            tableBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create(PropertyName);
            BindingFieldProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
            binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE,
                    Table,
                    tableBeanProperty,
                    jTextField,
                    BindingFieldProperty);
            Converter<Object, String> old = binding.getConverter();

            Converter<Object, String> converter = new Converter<Object, String>() {
                @Override
                public String convertForward(Object value) {
                    try {

                        if (value instanceof HashMap) {
                            HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) value;
                            System.out.println(hashMap);
                            // Object get = hashMap.get(GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID));
                            return (String) hashMap.get(GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID));

                        } else if (value instanceof String) {
                            return (String) value;
                        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                            Integer integer = (Integer) value;
                            return integer.toString();
                        } else if (value instanceof Float) {
                            Float float1 = (Float) value;
                            return float1.toString();
                        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                            Double double1 = (Double) value;
                            return double1.toString();
                        } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                            Date date = (Date) value;
                            return date.toLocalDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
                        }
                        MyLogger.Log_to_local(new Exception("Binding Class Not Handled" + value.getClass().getName()));
                        return "";

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        MyLogger.Log_to_local(e);

                    }
                    return "impossible";
                }

                @Override
                public Object convertReverse(String value) {
                    try {
                        return value;

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    return null;
                }

            };
            binding.setConverter(converter);
            binding.bind();
     } else 
     //
     //
     //    other component as JPasswordField .....
```

then it comes the part were i try to bind a JComboBox i tried this two versions :

```
                    if (Field instanceof JComboBox) {
                    //<editor-fold>
                    System.out.println("binding ");
                    JComboBox jComboBox = (JComboBox) Field;

                    BeanProperty<JComboBox, String> BindingFieldProperty;
                    Binding<JTable, Object, JComboBox, String> binding;
                    DesignCallID = jComboBox.getName();
                    PropertyName = "selectedElement." + GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID);
                    System.out.println("property name =" + PropertyName.trim());

                    tableBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create(PropertyName);
                    BindingFieldProperty = BeanProperty.create("selectedItem");
                    binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE,
                            Table,
                            tableBeanProperty,
                            jComboBox,
                            BindingFieldProperty);
                    Converter<Object, String> old = binding.getConverter();

                    Converter<Object, String> converter = new Converter<Object, String>() {
                        @Override
                        public String convertForward(Object value) {
                            try {

                                if (value instanceof HashMap) {
                                    HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) value;
                                    System.out.println(hashMap);
                                    // Object get = hashMap.get(GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID));
                                    return (String) hashMap.get(GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID));

                                } else if (value instanceof String) {
                                    return (String) value;
                                } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                                    Integer integer = (Integer) value;
                                    return integer.toString();
                                } else if (value instanceof Float) {
                                    Float float1 = (Float) value;
                                    return float1.toString();
                                } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                                    Double double1 = (Double) value;
                                    return double1.toString();
                                } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                                    Date date = (Date) value;
                                    return date.toLocalDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
                                }
                                MyLogger.Log_to_local(new Exception("Binding Class Not Handled" + value.getClass().getName()));
                                return "";

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                MyLogger.Log_to_local(e);

                            }
                            return "impossible";
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Object convertReverse(String value) {
                            try {
                                return value;

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                    };
                    binding.setConverter(converter);
                    binding.bind();
                       //</editor-fold>
                }
```

and the other version is :

```
                    System.out.println("binding jcombobox");
                    JComboBox jComboBox = (JComboBox) Field;

                    BeanProperty<JComboBox, Integer> BindingFieldProperty;
                    Binding<JTable, Object, JComboBox, Integer> binding;
                    DesignCallID = jComboBox.getName();
                    PropertyName = "selectedElement." + GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID);
                    System.out.println("property name =" + PropertyName.trim());

                    tableBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create(PropertyName);
                    BindingFieldProperty = BeanProperty.create("selectedItem");
                    binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE,
                            Table,
                            tableBeanProperty,
                            jComboBox,
                            BindingFieldProperty);
                    Converter<Object, Integer> old = binding.getConverter();

                    Converter<Object, Integer> converter = new Converter<Object, Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public Integer convertForward(Object value) {
                            try {

                                if (value instanceof HashMap) {
                                    HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) value;
                                    System.out.println(hashMap);
                                    // Object get = hashMap.get(GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID));
                                    return Integer.parseInt(""+hashMap.get(GetCorrespondingColumn(Table, DesignCallID)));

                                } else if (value instanceof String) {
                                    return Integer.parseInt(""+value);
                                } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                                    Integer integer = (Integer) value;
                                    return integer;
                                } else if (value instanceof Float) {
                                    Float float1 = (Float) value;
                                    return  float1.intValue();
                                } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                                    Double double1 = (Double) value;
                                    return double1.intValue();
                                } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                                    Date date = (Date) value;
                                    MyLogger.Log_to_local(new Exception("Binding Class Not Handled" + value.getClass().getName()));
                                    return 1;
                                }
                                MyLogger.Log_to_local(new Exception("Binding Class Not Handled" + value.getClass().getName()));
                                return 1;

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                MyLogger.Log_to_local(e);

                            }
                            return 1;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Object convertReverse(Integer value) {
                            try {
                                return value;

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                    };
                    binding.setConverter(converter);
                    binding.bind();
```

I dont know were I missed, It doesn't work for the JcomboBox !
So please is there any mistake or missed logic tell me AND also is there a solution to bind my JComboBox by code to my JTable show me how.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

First,IMO, you are providing code with more than 100 lines of code so most of the people will not willing to go through the question.
Back to your question,the possible answer to your question is using `setCellEditor` method.As the code below

```
//provided you have instatiate the table.
//then instantiate the `TableColumn` object to accept the column
TableColumn sportColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
...
//add the desired items to be selected by the user
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
comboBox.addItem("Chasing toddlers");
comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
comboBox.addItem("Teaching high school");
comboBox.addItem("None");
//add the combo box into the column
sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Here is the reference:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox

Comment: the question is not about rendring a table column as a combobox is about binding event of a combobox content to a the content (value of a column )